# stringified json vs json object memory usage in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

Just seeing if anyone has experience with the following. If I want to store a nested JSON object which may have anywhere from 10 to 500 key:string pairs, is it better to store the nested JSON object as a string or keep it as an object? What will the memory penalty be like for keeping the value as a JSON object rather than string?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size of document with Object.bsonsize() in the mongoshell

For example:

```
> Object.bsonsize({})
5
> Object.bsonsize({a:''})
13
> Object.bsonsize({a:'',b:''})
21
> Object.bsonsize({a:'',b:'',c:''})
29

> Object.bsonsize({a:{a:'',b:'',c:''}})
37
> Object.bsonsize({a:{a:'',b:''}})
29
> Object.bsonsize({a:{a:''}})
21

> Object.bsonsize({a:"{a:'',b:'',c:''}"})
29
> Object.bsonsize({a:"{a:'',b:''}"})
24
> Object.bsonsize({a:"{a:''}"})
19

> Object.bsonsize({a:""})
13
> Object.bsonsize({ab:""})
14
> Object.bsonsize({abc:""})
15
```

It looks like for me that empty doc is 5 byte one empty string is 7 byte plus each character in the name is 1 byte and each in the content is 1 byte.

Comment: Just to add to @attish's research, you should measure the memory usage on the application side using the object vs. adding the JSON.parse call on the string.